# Connect Backwards through SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, proxy

A bit of an odd question, but I'd like to give it a shot. I'm working with a company who's setup is a bit over secure (if you can even say that), essentially the server has block all outbound connections, except if you SSH/VNC in to the server (Ubuntu based).

Would it be possible to setup a proxy back through that SSH connection after I log in? So for example, I could allow a browser connection to pass through after my computer as it connects through SSH?

I know, I said the question was odd. Any help is apprecieated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest method in this case, with SSH access, would be a SOCKS proxy.

Not sure what you're working with on your local machine, but you can do it with whatever.

**First, set up the tunnel**

*nix:

```
ssh -ND PORTNUM user@server
```

The port isn't a big deal, the most common alternate HTTP port is 8080 since it isn't system reserved (I think 1 - 1024 are, or most anyway).

Windows

Using PUTTY (CLI or GUI) [How-To](https://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/).

- GUI Method

  2. Open PUTTY
  3. Navigate to `Connection > SSH > Tunnels`
  4. Choose Source Port (8080 or whatever), Dynamic, and Auto.
  5. Select 'Add' and then go back to the first screen, enter the server and log-in.  (a CLI option exists too if you want to put putty in your `PATH`.

Proceed to set up the browser.

**Second, set up the Browser**:

Then you would need to set your browser to use a SOCKS proxy over the specified port for traffic.  [Lifehacker Link](http://lifehacker.com/237227/geek-to-live--encrypt-your-web-browsing-session-with-an-ssh-socks-proxy).

**Warning**

I would, however, guess that the restrictions are in place for a reason and that you should ask if this is okay before doing it.  There is potential that an employer with restrictions such as those in place watch for tunnels and such as well and traffic to/from the server won't be encrypted so they could see what you're up to.

Comment: I thank you for the warning, luckily my employer is aware! They simply are looking for a workaround without changing their security. The method you explained theorectially makes perfect sense and should of worked, but something with their security is unfortunetly blocking it. Even after running netstat on the server, it can't see any new port listening and won't let me proxychain anything through. The answer is still correct though, thanks again!